# Magento Cloud - how to set my key for magento

Tags: magento2, command-line

How do I setup New Relic license key for my magento on the **magento cloud**? I don't use Magento CLI often

```
magento-cloud variable:set php:newrelic.license AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

I execute above by SSH

but it gave me this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

my account user right is not able to allow to perform this action. I asked the admin to help and he was able to create this variable on master